# I can't access to a php page

Tags: apache

I have created a simple php page on var/www/tuto director, but when I'm trying to open this page (this is it's URL :  `http://localhost/tuto/index.php` ) I got this message :

> ## Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /tuto/index.php on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Check for file persmissions on that page

Comment: You have written PHP but you try to open html file? Please clarify...

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? Try also replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" and check file permission too.

Comment: @OmniPotens I've installed Apache yesterday

Comment: @PiyasDe sorry my bad, this problem is for all files in the directory var/www/tuto

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I have this error meassage for each page in the directory  var/www/tuto

Comment: If the problem is only in your "tuto" folder, then ensure there's no .htaccess file inside of it demanding one or two things you'll need to edit. Check well your "tuto" folder

Comment: Check for proper directory permissions on `/var/www/tuto` then

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ this is the directory's permissions  `drwx------  5 aimad aimad 4096 Mar 16 14:10 tuto `

Comment: @OmniPotens there is no .htaccess file inside of the **tuto** folder

Comment: See if this link will help you with some ideas. http://www.matthewwittering.co.uk/blog/ubuntu-tips/apache-not-running-php-files.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tuto` directory has `aimad` as group and owner.
The `drwx------` means only you have read/write/execute permission on the directory.

- `d` means the node is directory
- `r(4)` means read permission
- `w(2)` means write permission
- `x(1)` means execute permission

The order for permissions is user, group, world.

To fix that you'll need to correct the permissions so apache can read from it. This is done with this command.

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/tuto
```

- user: `7` = r + w + x
- group: `5` = r + x
- world: `5` = r + x

It will set the correct permission for the directory and everything inside.

An even better approach would be to change the directory's group to `www-data` which apache uses on Ubuntu and then set the permissions to allow the group.

```
chown -R aimad:www-data /var/www/tuto
chmod -R 750 /var/www/tuto
```

To get a better understanding of how permissions work look at the Wikipedia page.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions